# How to create fixed footer/header with PDFKit in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit in rails to generate a PDF.

```
kit = PDFKit.new(html)
kit.stylesheets << 'app/assets/stylesheets/pdf.css'
kit.to_pdf
```

The PDF renders properly based on the HTML. I'm just curious how to introduce a fixed footer/header. For instance, if I like to add a page number fixed at the bottom of the page along with a logo on every single page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I just dug into the gem more and saw the :header_center option.

Looks like I'll be able to pass in value (probably a template as well) when creating the PDF like so.

```
kit = PDFKit.new(html, :header_center => "foo", :footer_center => "bar")
```

Comment: PDFKit.new takes all options wkhtmltopdf supports, see http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt for the complete list (search for footer)

Comment: Thanks @BrunoE. that's what I was looking for.